# How to get rid of Go routine "process" after the GO routine times out?

Tags: go, concurrency, stdin, goroutine

I have an interesting challenge.
I have a go routine that should display an error message for 4 seconds or until I press any key.
If I press a key within the 4 seconds it works as expected but if I don't press anything and let the timer pass,
my next input will be missing the first character.
I believe it is because the os.Stdin.Read from the previous Go Routine is not closing properly and still waits for my input.
How do I get rid of the go routine so  I can continue scanning for user input?

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    wait()
    var input string
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &input)
    fmt.Printf("%s", input)

}

func defaultTerminal() {
    exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "cooked").Run()
    exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "echo").Run()
}
func cbreak() {
    exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "cbreak", "min", "1").Run()

    exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "-echo").Run()
}

func readInput(input chan byte) {
    name := []byte("0")
    os.Stdin.Read(name)
    input <- name[0]
}

func wait() {
    fmt.Println("press any key to skip error message and dont wait for timer")
    cbreak()
    input := make(chan byte, 1)
    defer defaultTerminal()
    go readInput(input)
    select {
    case i := <-input:
        fmt.Printf("skipped timer with %v", i)

    case <-time.After(4 * time.Second):
        fmt.Printf("waited for timer")

    }
}
```

I tried using a quit channel but the issue persisted. I couldn't find any information on this problem on the internet.

Comment: You need to terminate readInput once timer.After fires. Note that reading from stdin like you do is not "cancelable".  Instead of execing to stty you should just use a library which handles all this for you e.g. termbox-go (https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go) or tcell, or ...